# Bigcommerce customize Export Template

Tags: bigcommerce

I want to get the product URL with my site URL . But there is only csv export comes with only simple product URL.

this is the product URL :  /intel-core-i3-2100-3-1ghz-oem-cpu-sr05c-cm8062301061600/

But I want with : www.example.com/intel-core-i3-2100-3-1ghz-oem-cpu-sr05c-cm8062301061600/

Now it is The relative path of  product's URL. I need to get the absolute path of product's URL .
How can i do it ?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to change the way the URL exports to export the absolute path. You'd need to use something like the Excel concatenate function to manipulate the data after export.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CONCATENATE-function-8f8ae884-2ca8-4f7a-b093-75d702bea31d

Comment: This is the manual way. but i wants the automatically way . one more question is there any way to product export csv automatically save on any particular server location ? like with cron job or anything else.

Comment: You might be able to use something like Selenium to automate the export and save it to a folder in WebDAV. Another way to automate the export would be to have your application pull that data via API, either at timed intervals or when an event is triggered with a webhook. Then, you could convert the JSON to CSV, if that's the format you need it in.